# R: How to Statistically Analyse Paired Data in a Data Set Which Has a Gathered Format?

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I have a large data set similar in structure to this small data set:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
Time_point <- c("T0", "T0", "T0", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2")
Score <- c(35, 45, 25, 45, 45, 40, 60, 50, 40)
Practice_h <- c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(ID, Time_point, Score, Practice_h)
rm(ID, Time_point, Score, Practice_h)

df

  ID Time_point Score Practice_h
1  1        T0    35         NA
2  2        T0    45         NA
3  3        T0    25         NA
4  1        T1    45          2
5  2        T1    45          0
6  3        T1    40          3
7  1        T2    60          2
8  2        T2    50          1
9  3        T2    40          1
```

Two questions:

1) I would like to run a *paired* t-test comparing the scores of different individuals (indicated by the ID) at different time points. How can I do that without having to spread the data set?

2) I would like to do a simple regression, checking if practice influences the *differences* in the scores. For this, I would need to calculate the difference between score at T2 and T1 for each ID. Any idea how I can do that using this data organization?

(The reason why I don't want to spread my data like below is that plotting of scores grouped by time point in a single plot is problematic in this format.)

```
  ID score_T0 score_T1 score_T2 practice_T1 practice_T2
1  1       35       45       60           2           2
2  2       45       45       50           0           1
3  3       25       40       40           3           1
```

I know this is a lot to ask, and I'm very thankful for any help I can get, even partial answers. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just transform (e.g. `spread`) the data for calculation and keep the original format for plotting? It is very common to have different shapes of the same data for different tasks.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'm pretty new to data analysis in R, so I was wondering if there is an easier way of keeping everything together. But if it's normal to have different shapes, I'll probably do the same :) Thank you!

Comment: Could you give an explanation/example about number 1 in your questions? I am interpreting it as wanting to find the difference and do a single difference paired t-test.

Comment: In question 1 I would like to do a paired t-test between different time points, for example all scores for T0 compared to all scores for T1. But since the scores are in different rows here and not in different columns, I do not know how to perform a t-test on them. Does that make sense?